# Trouble using python PIL library to crop and save image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Im attempting to crop a pretty high res image and save the result to make sure its completed.  However I keep getting the following error regardless of how I use the save method: `SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image`

```
from PIL import Image

# size is width/height
img = Image.open('0_388_image1.jpeg')
box = (2407, 804, 71, 796)
area = img.crop(box)

area.save('cropped_0_388_image1', 'jpeg')
output.close()
```

Comment: Also note that if the area has width or height equals to 0 like `(0, 0, 0, 10)` or `(0, 0, 10, 0)` it will raise the same error.

Comment: @Natim You solved my problem.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The box is (left, upper, right, lower) so maybe you meant (2407, 804, 2407+71, 804+796)?

**Edit**: All four coordinates are measured from the top/left corner, and describe the distance from that corner to the left edge, top edge, right edge and bottom edge.

Your code should look like this, to get a 300x200 area from position 2407,804:

```
left = 2407
top = 804
width = 300
height = 200
box = (left, top, left+width, top+height)
area = img.crop(box)
```

Comment: :)  Yes indeed the image is that big.  Its almost 1Mg .. its an image of an intersection

what i understood is this:  the documentation says left upper(top) right lower(bottom) which is EXACTLY what I put in.  The pixel coords are 2407 from the LEFT 804 pixels from the TOP 71 pixels from the RIGHT and 796 pixels from the BOTTOM.  I dont see where I erred.  

the box thus described crops a vehicle's back end

Comment: All the coordinates are measured from the top/left corner, and describe the distance from that corner to the left edge, top edge, right edge and bottom edge.

Comment: I must be retarded.  I tried what I thought you meant and now its a small little sliver:
box = (1465, 1788, 3801, 1796)

Comment: oh my GOD.  Am I stupid?  Was that obvious?  

And what happened to the other guy?  he didnt want to be seen on this thread ??  ;0)

Comment: Got it.  Why must I comment on everyones response?  why cant I comment once for everyone?

Comment: Thanks! To say something to everyone, you should edit your question.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

it's a simple code to crop an image, and it works like a charm ;)

```
import Image

def crop_image(input_image, output_image, start_x, start_y, width, height):
    """Pass input name image, output name image, x coordinate to start croping, y coordinate to start croping, width to crop, height to crop """
    input_img = Image.open(input_image)
    box = (start_x, start_y, start_x + width, start_y + height)
    output_img = input_img.crop(box)
    output_img.save(output_image +".png")

def main():
    crop_image("Input.png","output", 0, 0, 1280, 399)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

In this case the Input image is 1280 x 800 px and the croped is 1280 x 399px starting at the top left corner.