# Auto-cropping images with PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, image-manipulation, python-imaging-library, crop

I have folder full of images with each image containing at least 4 smaller images. I would to know how I can cut the smaller images out using Python PIL so that they will all exist as independent image files. fortunately there is one constant, the background is either white or black so what I'm guessing I need is a way to the cut these images out by searching for rows or preferably columns which are entirely black or entirely white, Here is an example image:

[image]

From the image above, there would be 10 separate images, each containing a number. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have another sample image that is more realistic in the sense that the backgrounds of some of the smaller images are the same colour as the background of the image they are contained in. e.g.

[image]

The output of which being 13 separate images, each containng 1 letter

Comment: A similar question on cropping is asked before...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076638/trouble-using-python-pil-library-to-crop-and-save-image you can put that code in a loop with correct coordinates that change to make it work like autocrop

Comment: Thanks for the reply but The cropbox works from predefined x, y coords. As I stated, the only constant is the background color leaving entire columns of black/white. It would be quicker to do it manually than it would be to do it that way.

Comment: put in under some loop and increment the coordinates uniformly basically the left coordinate, that way I hope it is faster than manual intervention, also once the code is ready you can apply it to n number of images.

Comment: The image above was just used to help give clarity to my question, and yes it would work on said image. But, the images I have vary in size, as do the images that are contained within them. Looping from one image to the next would yield results that could be considered to be random. That's why I need to be able to to get PIL something similar to find 'all-black" pixel columns and split what's between them into separate images.

Answer (score 1):

Using scipy.ndimage for labeling:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import Image

THRESHOLD = 100
MIN_SHAPE = np.asarray((5, 5))

filename = "eQ9ts.jpg"
im = np.asarray(Image.open(filename))
gray = im.sum(axis=-1)
bw = gray > THRESHOLD
label, n = ndi.label(bw)
indices = [np.where(label == ind) for ind in xrange(1, n)]
slices = [[slice(ind[i].min(), ind[i].max()) for i in (0, 1)] + [slice(None)]
          for ind in indices]
images = [im[s] for s in slices]
# filter out small images
images = [im for im in images if not np.any(np.asarray(im.shape[:-1]) < MIN_SHAPE)]
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, the above code works great on the first example image, unfortunately I can't seem to tweak it to work with the 2nd image that I've not long added. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.